# Whose purpose is it in this 'in order to' clause?

Tags: meaning

In [an essay](https://www.thoughtco.com/brothers-grimm-german-folklore-4018397#:%7E:text=Friedrich%20Wilhelm%20IV%2C-,in%20order%20to,-continue%20their%20academic) about the Grimm Brothers, there is such a sentence:

> First, both lived again in Kassel but were invited to Berlin by the Prussian king, Friedrich Wilhelm IV, **in order to** *continue their academic work there*.

Whose purpose is it to 'continue their academic work there'? I came up with two ideas but can't figure out which is right:

1. The brothers accepted the king's invitation to live there because they wanted to continue their academic work there. (The king might know little about their current plan then.)
2. To provide the brothers convenience to continue their academic work, the king invited them.

Comment: @WeatherVane They actually accepted the invitation.

Comment: It's a purpose adjunct modifying the VP "were invited to Berlin by the Prussian king, Friedrich Wilhelm IV". The adjunct gives the purpose of the invitation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sentence states that the *invitation* was for that purpose, so it's (2). Otherwise it would be 'they accepted the King's invitation in order to...'

Answer (score 2):

Sentence (1) makes no mention of whether they accepted the invitation.

Sentence (2) is better, although the actual reason may not be. It might not have been for the convenience of the brothers, but because the king wanted their knowledge close at hand.

It means

> . . . **so that they could** continue their academic work there.